# Why can't I run a command as a user having /bin/false as login shell?

Tags: shell, login, su

I attach to a docker image where user has already been created with this command:

```
RUN useradd -r -u 200 -m -c "nexus role account" -d /nexus-data -s /bin/false nexus
```

I wanted to run a command as this user, but nothing happened. Trying to solve this, I discovered I can't run anything with a user having /bin/false as login:

```
# useradd xxx
# su xxx -c 'ls >>/t/t1'
# ls /t
t1
# useradd -s /bin/false
# su xxx1 -c 'ls >>/t/t2'
# ls /t
t1
```

I was expecting that login shell would not matter when calling su without `-`. I googled and I found out that I can run the command if I add `-s /bin/bash`, but why is that so? The `-` option is su means 'use login shell', why is the login shell relevant without `-`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't specify `-s` or `--preserve-environment` then the *target* user's shell is used.  In your example this would run `/bin/false -c 'ls >> /t/t2'` which, of course, doesn't run anything useful.

The "login shell" has a specific meaning and would cause normal shells such as `sh` or `bash` to run the login scripts such as `.profile`.