# Should I always set the root shell to /usr/bin/false?

Tags: shell, security, osx, root

To prevent abuse of the root account (on my macOS, single user) machine, should I always set the `root` shell to `/usr/bin/false` (or [`/sbin/nologin`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10867/9297))?

For example should I always:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/root UserShell /usr/bin/false
```

or are there common reasons not to do that (other than the [obvious and avoidable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293626/9297))?

Comment: Bear in mind that you are only here in the first place because of the bug that ends up creating a `root` record in the accounts database to order.  Apple's _intended_ mechanism for preventing abuse of the `root` account was, remember, to not have a record by that name in the accounts database to start with.

Comment: @JdeBP: Yes good point (and assumption). I assume now that it's there, the old standing recommendation to macOS users *not to create* a `root` account at all is no longer valid. (It also suggests that disabling the shell for that account might be the closest one can get, but they didn't do that in the patch, so perhaps not.)

Answer (score 10):

No, you should not, because then if you *need* to use the `root` account (as is sometimes the case, even on Macs) for troubleshooting or recovery, you cannot.

You *should*, however, set the root password:

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

Comment: [I'm getting conflicting advice.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307543/4395) And the macOS recommendation generally is (or has been) not to enable `root` at all. (I have no idea which approach is right. But that advice made sense to me just from a convenience and UX point of view: I didn't what a powerful account around that I'd never use and with a password I'd certainly forget.)

Comment: I have had several occasions where I needed to boot a Mac into Single-User mode (which logs in with the root user's default shell) in order to address filesystem or other issue that (e. g.)  Disk Utility on the Recovery image could not remedy.  If the root user's shell were (e. g.) `/bin/false`, this avenue would not have been available to me without moving the drive to another host, and could have been impossible if FileVault were in play.  _A_ password, even one you have forgotten, however, is still better than _no_ password.

Comment: That makes sense. (In fact, I now recall having to do exactly that once way back when the Mac was still a NeXT.) But I'm still getting conflicting advice ([comments here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307543/4395)), so I want to be sure.

Comment: I guess this hinges on [wether disabling the shell does indeed prevent Single User access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307664/4395).

Comment: That [appears to be wrong](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307666/4395). The command in the question will not affect Singe User mode. Can you clarify or confirm?

Comment: Can confirm it works.  A co-worker's Mac was using `zsh` in single-user as they had changed root's shell.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the root shell as you outlined, you cannot log in or `su -` to root. You an, however, still use `sudo` or even `su` (without the minus).

Disabling root login is generally a good security measure. You should, however, make sure that you can access the machine in some other way in case of a system failure. When the system behaves strangely, root login might still work when normal accounts don't (that is, for example, why on most Unix systems the root home directory is not in the normal user home directory, but on the system drive).

You can probably still boot into single-user mode, but I am not 100% sure on this with current MacOS versions, you should check. If this is still possible even with a no-login shell, this is your way out of trouble and you can safely disable root login.

If not, it becomes a question of which death you want to die. Decide for yourself what is more likely - someone abusing your root account or your system malfunctioning to the point where you would need that root account.

Answer (score 1):

### Day to day operations

You don't need the `root` account enabled to perform day to day operations on macOS. And even without an enabled root account and its shell set to `/usr/bin/false` you are still able to use `sudo` (and for `root` shells `sudo -s`) without problems.

### single user mode

Single user mode uses /private/etc/passwd for login authentication, not Open Directory:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ grep ^root: /etc/passwd 
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

but

```
pse@Mithos:~$ sudo dscl . -read /Users/root UserShell
UserShell: /usr/bin/false
```

So there will be no negative consequences on single user mode.